# Need to change a textcontent of span in JS Only if input is not empty (right now, it's updating all the time)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
const inputRef = document.querySelector('#name-input');
const textRef = document.querySelector('#name-output');
inputRef.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (event.target.value != '') {
    textRef.textContent = event.target.value;
  } else {
    textRef.textContent;
  }
});
```

Need to change a `textContent` value of span only if `event.target.value` is not empty. Right now it's changing inappropriately.

How can I get back default value of span, if input is not empty. Let's say I have a string "Hello, visitor" - right there, 'visitor' is span. If I'm not passing anything to input - I'm getting "Hello, visitor". If I have passed "Alex", it's returning "Hello, Alex", but i delete everything - it will be just "Hello," instead of "Hello, visitor".

Comment: Initially, textContent of span (textRef) is not empty, what do you expect in this case? The value will never be set.

Comment: @Rayon have updated the question.

Comment: It does work as per your expectations. https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kymxrgLw/

Comment: When I delete the content of input, I want it to get back to its span default value, I don't want it save the last input I did.

Comment: But it is working as per this statement `event.target.value != ''`

Comment: How can I get back default value of span, if input is not empty. Let's say I have a string "Hello, visitor" - right there, 'visitor' is span. If I'm not passing anything to input - I'm getting "Hello, visitor". If I have passed "Alex", it's returning "Hello, Alex", but i delete everyting - it will be just "Hello," instead of "Hello, visitor". @Rayon

Comment: @Rayon now you got the idea what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a variable holding a default value. If input is empty, use `default` value as a textContent of `span`

```js
const inputRef = document.querySelector('#name-input');
const textRef = document.querySelector('#name-output');
let defaultValue = 'Visitor';
inputRef.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (event.target.value != '') {
    textRef.textContent = event.target.value;
  } else {
    textRef.textContent = defaultValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="name-input" />
<span>Hello, </span><span id="name-output">Visitor</span>
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you so much, Rayon!